# SQL Server setup check list

Tags: sql-server, raid, tempdb

What are the things I have to consider when I have to install SQL Server (2005/2008) on a new server?

- Storage setup
- TempDB
- Security

What are some common mistakes made in that process?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please see Brent Ozar's great post on the topic:
http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/03/sql-server-2005-setup-checklist-part-1-before-the-install/

Comment: WOW, dude, that's the first time I've ever seen somebody else quote my setup checklist.  I'm flattered.  I'm so used to going into these questions and copy/pasting my own link to my checklist - now somebody else is doing it for me. Love it!  So of course I gotta upvote ya, heh.

Comment: Brent's list is very thorough, I would add: make sure anti-virus is configured to bypass sql database files either by location or extension.

Comment: SqlACID - great point, and I'll add that to the checklist.

Answer (score 3):

I usually revoke the `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission. By doing this each user can only see the databases they are able to access (it also helps simplifying the list in SQL Server Management Studio):

```
USE master
REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM PUBLIC
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Not offense to Brent Ozar, but Chad Boyd also has a very good series of SQL checklists:

- [Pre-SQL Installation](http://blogs.mssqltips.com/blogs/chadboyd/pages/checklist-3-pre-sql-installation.aspx)
- [Post-SQL Installation](http://blogs.mssqltips.com/blogs/chadboyd/pages/checklist-4-post-sql-installation.aspx)
- [Pre-Cluster Installation](http://blogs.mssqltips.com/blogs/chadboyd/pages/checklist-1-pre-cluster-installation.aspx)
- [Post-Cluster Configuration](http://blogs.mssqltips.com/blogs/chadboyd/pages/checklist-2-post-cluster-configuration.aspx)

The cluster checklists, in particular, are invaluable.

Comment: Links have been moved for this old answer, here you can find these
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlserverauthor/2/chad-boyd/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the Express version, here are some tips for the network connectivity configuration:

[SQL Server 2008 Express Installation Checklist](http://donnedwards.openaccess.co.za/2009/02/sql-server-2008-express-installation.html)

> *"Out of the box, SQL Server Express's
> network connectivity settings aren't
> enabled."*
>
> Talk about an understatement!